# how to deal with complex branching in templates?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-templates

I have a table like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.Charfield(blank=True, ...)
    date=models.Charfield(blank=True, ...)
    author=models.Charfield(blank=True, ...)
    ...
```

I need to display this info like this: `<p>Title (date), author</p>`
But the problem is that all these fields are optional, which makes me to create this monstrous construction in the template:

```
{% if book.title or book.date or book.author %}
    <p>
    {% if book.title %}
        {{ book.title }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if book.date %}
        ({{ book.date }})
    {% endif %}
    {% if book.title or book.date and book.author %}
        ,
    {% endif %}
    {% if book.author %}
        {{ book.author }}
    {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

Should it be like this or am I doing something wrong?
Should I move this logic to the model, where I can do it in a cleaner way with python etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    p = []
    if self.title:
        p.append(self.title)
    if self.date:
        p.append(u'(%s)' % self.data)
        p = [u' '.join(p)]
    if book.author:
        p.append(book.author)  # p.append(unicode(book.author))
    return u', '.join(p)            

def as_p(self):
    p = unicode(self)
    return u'<p>%s</p>' % p if p else u''
```

In the template:

```
{{ book.as_p }}
```